# f951 error: unrecognized command line option

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, fortran, compiler-warnings, fortran90

I am on linux and I am compiling the following:

```
mpif90 -shared source.F90 object1.o object2.o -L/some/path -Qoption,link,-rpath=/some/path -I/some/path -lhdf5 -lhdf5_fortran -fPIC -fpp -DDECDEC_ -DMSMS_  -cxxlib-gcc -o libhdfwrapper.so
```

and I get

```
f95: unrecognized option '-Qoption,link,-rpath=/some/path'
f95: unrecognized option '-cxxlib-gcc'
f951: error: unrecognized command line option "-fpp"
```

can anybody tell me why fpp is not recognized?

Answer (score 2):

`-fpp` is a flag used by some compilers, notably Solaris Studio. Also `-rpath` seems to point to Solaris Studio. It seems you are using gfortran or some other compiler, however. Other compilers use `-cpp` instead. The same holds for the other options.

Also, the part `-Qoption,link,-rpath=/some/path` is probably not in the right format.

You may want to consult http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/documentation/oss-translate-gfortran-180584.pdf and your compiler's manual.